# Likelihood ratio test for multinomial logistic regression with an interaction in R

Tags: r, regression, interaction, multinomial

In a data set I have the following variables:

• freehms: opinion if gays and lesbians free to live as they wish

• prtvtcie: Party participant voted for

• trstplt: Trust in politicians

• agea: Calculated age of the participant

• gndr_dummy: Dummy variable for gender

I want to estimate the fit of two multinomial logistic regression models using a likelihood ratio test, one with interaction and one without an interaction term between level of trust (trstplt) and opinion on lesbian/gays (freehms).

I have estimated the following model - without interaction:

```
model_without_interaction <- multinom(prtvtcie ~ freehms + agea + gndr_dummy, data = ie)
```

For the model with interaction term, I have estimated the following term:

```
model_with_interaction <- multinom(prtvtcie ~ freehms + trstplt + freehms*trstplt + agea + gndr_dummy, data = ie22)
```

I use the likelihood ratio test, to test whether the interaction term between level of trust (trstplt) and opinion on lesbian/gays (freehms) adds additional value to the model.

For this I have used the following code:

```
lrtest(model_with_interaction,"freehms * trstplt")
```

However, I receive the following error message:
<kbd>Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable) : cannot find inherited method for function 'lrtest' for signature '"multinom"'.</kbd>

So my question is: How can I estimate a likelihood ratio test?

Answer (score 1):

You need:

```r
model_without_interaction <- multinom(prtvtcie ~ freehms + 
 agea + gndr_dummy, data = ie)

model_with_interaction <- multinom(prtvtcie ~ freehms*trstplt + 
 agea + gndr_dummy, data = ie22)

lrtest(model_without_interaction, model_with_interaction)
```

The null hypothesis of the test is that the `model_with_interaction` is not better than the `model_without_interaction`.  Also I see that you're using two different data frames for these models.  For the LR test to work, the models have to be estimated on the same set of observations.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a conflict with the `VGAM`-Package. To solve HW2, you might want to specify where your function should stem from.

```
lmtest::lrtest(model_without_interaction, model_with_interaction)
```

If you get the Error that the datasets are not the same size, you have to reestimate the model without interaction and filter out NA's (see hint on the exercise sheet).

```
nominal_model_interact <- multinom(party_vote ~ freehms*trust + age + sex,
                  data = df_it,
                  weights = dweight)

nominal_model_nafree <- multinom(party_vote ~ freehms + age + sex,
                      data = df_it %>% filter(!is.na(freehms)),
                      weights = dweight)
```